# Delphi equivalent of .net's DateTime.ToString("s") (DateTime Sortable)

Tags: c#, .net, delphi, function

Is there an equivalent in Delphi?  I've looked over the documentation and can't find anything that would give me the output I want.

Comment: Since many Delphi developers are not that knowledgeable in the world of .NET, you might want to specify what "s" does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

kdunlapmo, the [DateTime.ToString(“s”)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1%28VS.71%29.aspx) function return an Sortable date/time pattern; conforms to ISO 8601. this pattern is declarated as `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"`. regardless of the culture, the date must always be returned in the same format. you can use the FormatDateTime function in delphi to format an TDateTime value into a string.

you can use something like this

```
FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mm:ss', Now);
```

but you must be careful because the `-` character is Substituted by the [DateSeparator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.DateSeparator) value and the `:` character is Substituted by the [TimeSeparator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/SysUtils.TimeSeparator) value, both variables are depending on the Windows locale configuration. so to avoid problems getting distinct results when the culture changes you must use explicity the `-` and the `:` characters in your format string.

```
FormatDateTime('yyyy"-"mm"-"dd"T"hh":"mm":"ss', Now)
```

see this sample code

```
program ProjectTestFormat;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

begin
  try        
    DateSeparator:='/';
    TimeSeparator:='.';
    //this string is affected by the windows locale configuration
    Writeln(FormatDateTime('yyyy-mm-dd"T"hh:mm:ss', Now));
    //this string is not affected
    Writeln(FormatDateTime('yyyy"-"mm"-"dd"T"hh":"mm":"ss', Now));
    Readln;
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

Additionally you can write a function to convert an TDatetime value to the sortable format, see this sample

```
function GetSortableDatetimeFormat(Value:TDateTime):string;
begin
  Result:=FormatDateTime('yyyy"-"mm"-"dd"T"hh":"mm":"ss', Value);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Little bugfix - right is:

> Result:=FormatDateTime('yyyy"-"mm"-"dd"T"hh":"nn":"ss', Value);

(minutes is "nn", not "mm")